# Cordova/phonegap Googleplus

Tags: javascript, cordova, oauth

So I'm trying to do google oauth in my phonegap app. Since inappbroswer is being depreciated by google, I've been trying other options. The plugin I'm trying to get working is googleplus: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

I've downloaded the demo html, and installed the plugin in my testing IOS app. This is the response I'm getting when I click on a link:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.googleplus.login');
file://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B6EF7424-A173-49A5-85A4-7EF0C0517B4D/Library/NoCloud/phonegapdevapp/www/index.html; 384
```

I'm not sure if I did something wrong in my credentials setup or plugin installation.